# Rank the functions in increasing order of growth

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

> Rank the functions in increasing order of growth:
>
> F1(n) = n^(n/2)
> F2(n) = (n/2)^n
> F3(n) = (log n)^(log n)
> F4(n) = 8^(log n)
> F5(n) = n^(4/3)
> F6(n) = n^3 - n^2
> F7(n) = 2^(log n)^2
> F8(n) = n log n

I have the functions ranked as follows:
F8 < F5 < F6 ~ F4 < F3 < F7 < F1 ~ F2

f(n) < g(n) means f(n) = Little-o(g(n)) and
f(n) ~ g(n) means f(n) = Big-Theta(g(n))

Appreciate any second opinions on this! Particularly, F1 and F2 as well as F6 and F4.

Main intuition that I used was linear < polynomial < exponential and simplifying certain functions such as F4(n) = 8^(log n) = n^3  and F7(n) = 2^(log n)^2 = n^(log n).

Comment: How did you come up with your rankings? Please show your work.

Comment: log(F1)=n/2 log n, log(F2)=n(log n - log 2). So F2 > F1. That's the sort of reasoning you have to do, rather than "opinions"

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I am new to the subject hence am not too familiar with the reasonings. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Ranking of the functions should be:
F3(n) < F7(n) < F4(n) < F8(n) < F5(n) < F6(n) < F1(n) < F2(n)

- F3(n) - Logarithmic functions grow slower than polynomial functions, and in general, exponential functions with larger bases grow faster than those with smaller bases.
- F4(n) will grow faster than F7(n), while they will both grow at an exponential rate, the base of the function will determine the rate of growth. Also, you can write 8^(log(n)) as 2^(3log(n)). Even though F4(n) is faster than F7(n), it is still slower than the polynomial function.
- F8(n) grows faster than logarithmic function but is smaller than polynomial function like n^2, n^3, n^4, ...
- F5(n) grows faster than F8(n) but is slower than the polynomial function like n^2, n^3, n^4, ...
- F6(n) is a polynomial function of degree 3 and is faster than the F5(n), but is slower than the exponential function F1(n).
- F2(n) > F1(n) - If you take the logarithm of both sides you get log((n/2)^n)=n(log(n) - log(2)) > log(n^(n/2))=(n/2)log(n).

Comment: I believe F4 > F8. F4 is polynomial: If we use the base 2 logarithm, then F4(n) = n^3. With the natural logarithm, it is still faster than n^2, so definitely faster than nlog(n).

Comment: @Berthur You need to take logarithm of both sides, in which case you will get log(n)*log(8)=3*log(n)*log(8) on one side and log(n*log(n)) on the other. Changing just one side will make the final comparison incorrect. With that being said, I still think that F4 < F8. Here is a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kqzl3sli5x) of both functions side by side for comparison.

Comment: It looks like Desmos uses *log(x) = log_10(x)*, in which case what you say is true. But try changing it to *log_2* or *log_e*. Of course we cannot know which log base this exercise defaults to, but in computer science context, it is often taken as base *e*, or sometimes base *2*, but not so often base *10*.

Comment: @Berthur I think the base of log is often omitted in cs due to change of base rule. Changing the base of logarithm means multiplying them by a constant, which means that the difference is just a constant factor, so it doesn't affect the end result. Even with a log_2, can you explain how did you get n^3, because log_2(8^(log_2(n)))= log_2(2^(3*log_2(n)))=3*log_2(n)*log_2(2)=3*log_2(n)?

Comment: That is true when the logarithm is a factor, like *O(n log n)*, where the base makes no difference. But if you have the logarithm as an exponent, then it matters: *8^log_2(n) = 2^(3log_2(n)) = 2^log_2(n^3) = n^3*

Comment: @Berthur I completely missed that. Yes, you are correct, *8^log_2(n) = n^3*.  However, I'm still not convinced that it should be F4 > F8. What if you had to compare 7^log(n) and n*log(n)?

Comment: Then it's just a less pretty expression, but still greater than *nlogn*. Just look at the graphs after fixing the log base :) The only question here is which base does the exercise assume?